# How to make the code more readable (for-loop or apply)

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

In my `R` code I’m using variables `mydata1, mydata2, mydata3, …, mydataN` that are store results of the `function1()`:

```
mydata1 <- function1() 
mydata2 <- function1()
mydata3 <- function1()
#…
mydataN <- function1()
```

Variables `mydata1, mydata2, mydata3, …, mydataN` can be the vectors, matrices or data.frames.

Later I pass variables `mydata1, mydata2, mydata3, …, mydataN` as input values of the `function2()` and save results in the new variables `newmydata1, newmydata2, …, newmydata1`:

```
newmydata1<- function2(mydata1) 
newmydata2<- function2(mydata2)
newmydata3<- function2(mydata3)
#…
newmydataN<- function2(mydataN)
```

I now the number `N` before calculation.

**Question.** How to make the code more functional and readable? 
Should I use the `for-loop` or a function from the `apply` family?

Comment: Save all variables as elements in list to avoid many objects flooding global environment. Then use `lapply` on list of objects: `newlist <- lapply(mylist, myfunction)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this concrete and runnable define the initial list, `L0` and functions used as in the Note at the end.

In the following solutions `L3`, `LL`, `L`, `out4`, `out4a` and `out5` are all identical.

**1) Repeated lapply**

```
L1 <- lapply(L0, function1)
L2 <- lapply(L1, function2)
L3 <- lapply(L2, function3)
```

**2) Reduce**

```
FL <- list(function1, function2, function3)
LL <- Reduce(lapply, FL, init = L0)
```

**3) loop**   `FL` is as in (2).

```
L <- L0
for(f in FL) L <- Map(f, L)    # or for(f in FL) L <- lapply(L, f)
```

**4) magrittr**

```
library(magrittr)

L0 %>% lapply(function1) %>% lapply(function2) %>% lapply(function3) -> out4
```

**4a) magrittr variation**

```
library(magrittr)

L0 %>% lapply(. %>% function1 %>% function2 %>% function3) -> out4a
```

**5) functional::Compose**

```
library(functional)

out5 <- Map(Compose(function1, function2, function3), L0)
```

**Note:** Input used:

```
L0 <- as.list(1:4)
function1 <- function(x) x+1
function2 <- function(x) 2*x
function3 <- function(x) x^2
```